# Merge two cells in YUI datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I would like to know how to merge two existing cells in a YUI 2.9 datatable. Ie, row 1 has 3 columns, name, description, date. In rows 2 and 3, I want a name to be the same and description spanning over the last two columns. Then again a new set of rows like that - one row with all three columns, then a few of them with only two.

Is it possible and how can it be done?

Here's a mock of my current Datatable code:

```
var columnDefs = [
{key: "name", label: "Name"},
{key: "desc", label: "Description", formatter: this.descFormatter},
{key: "date", label: "Date", formatter: dateFormatter}
];

var dataTable = new YAHOO.util.DataTable(this.id + "-datatable", columnDefs, this.dataSource);
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with any version of YUI.

Comment: I found out some useful info here, for what its' worth: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/08/17/ask-satyam-row-expansion/

Comment: Ah yes. With YUI2 DataTable questions always ask Satyam :P